# Не отправляется почта с сервера

Tags: email, php, smtp, sendmail

```
Jan 27 14:12:16 vps-1018130-2745 sendmail[1776]: t0RBBDQ1001776: to=zoinx2010@mail.ru, ctladdr=admin@dverov.ru (500/502), delay=00:01:03, xdelay=00:01:03, mailer=relay, pri=30289, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with [127.0.0.1]
Jan 27 14:12:16 vps-1018130-2745 sendmail[1778]: t0RBCG5M001778: Authentication-Warning: vps-1018130-2745.host4g.ru: dverov set sender to admin@dverov.ru using -f
Jan 27 14:12:16 vps-1018130-2745 sendmail[1778]: t0RBCG5M001778: from=admin@dverov.ru, size=357, class=0, nrcpts=0, msgid=<201501271112.t0RBCG5M001778@vps-1018130-2745.host4g.ru>, relay=dverov@localhost
```

Логи такие, в чем может быть проблема и как решить?

Comment: @zoinx2012, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Написано же:

> Connection timed out with [127.0.0.1]

Попробуй для начала отправить письмо из консоли.